# Can't get variables on view that were set in JS files compiled by webpacker rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

**Rails 5.2.3**

**Webpacker 4.0.2**

I have `layouts/application.html.erb` where I call `dateFormat.initialize();`

this function is defined in `javascript/packs/application.js`

```
const dateFormat = {
  railsDateMask: "YYYY/MM/DD",

  initialize() {
  }
}
```

and when I go to the index page there is an exception in the browser console

`ReferenceError: dateFormat is not defined`

before - this code was in `assets/javascripts/application.js` and everything works fine

I have found a lot of explanations and one of the solutions was set it like not `const dateFormat` but like `global.dateFormat`, but I don't think that it's the best solution and maybe there is another way.

Comment: Have you check in javascripts/application.js there is a //= require packs/application? or //= require_tree . ?

Comment: I shouldn't check this file because if I add this to the `javascripts/application.js` it will be compiled by sprockets and I don't need it. As you can see in the title of my question and description - I'm trying to solve a problem that occurs when I use webpacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack doesn't export anything to the global scope by default. You could do something like `window.dateFormat = ...` like you suggested, but I prefer to configure Webpack to export selected modules instead. It's a little more work but a lot more flexible and a lot less error-prone.

First, you'll want to export your desired global references from your entry point(s). So, declare your object as an export from `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
export const dateFormat = { ... };
```

Now tell Webpack you want to export your output to the window target from your Webpack config in `config/webpack/environment.js`.

```
environment.config.merge({
  output: {
    library: ['Packs', '[name]'],
    libraryTarget: 'window',
  }
})
```

The above config says "make my application exports available on `window` from `Packs.application`". For example, to access your exported `dateFormat` object from the console or in your views, use `window.Packs.application.dateFormat`.

Note: the namespace `Packs.[name]` is arbitrary; use whatever suits your application. The `[name]` placeholder will create a separate namespace-per-entrypoint, which, if you end up using multiple entrypoints, would be helpful to prevent collisions.